# Using a userform to adjust a range of cells

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I am hoping someone can help me with a query. So far I have an excel spreadsheet and you select a cell and then click a button, the button opens a userform with a scroll bar on and as you use the scroll bar this edits the number in cell by +-1 up/down to bounds that you type into text boxes. This moves the graphs associated with each cell in real time. When I close the userform, the original values are populated back in the cells.

My hope is that when using the spreadsheet, eventually, people will be able to select a number of cells (a random number of cells, sometimes you might select 2 or 7 or 10 to change) and the userform will impact all of them in the same way above however I am having trouble with this. This will enable people to see the impact of the interaction between these items.

To make it work for one cell I have defined the variable as public outside the user form as so:

```
Public SelRange As Integer
```

Then within `UserForm_Initialize`:

```
SelRange = Selection
```

Then there is code for max, min, increments etc and when the scroll bar is used, the value is deposited in the active cell by the code:

```
Selection = SelRange
```

However if I select numerous cells and try do this I get a type mismatch which would suggest I should define the `SelRange` in a different way but I can't figure out what this is or even if that will actually help the situation.

Thanks for your help.

Full code below:

Code for Button:

```
        Public SelRange As Integer

        Sub Button1_Click()
        UserForm1.Show
        End Sub
```

Code for Scroll Bar within userform:

```
        Option Explicit
        ' Sets default values for when the Userform is opened
        Public Sub UserForm_Initialize()

        MinBox.Value = -100
        MaxBox.Value = 100
        IncBox.Value = 5

        SelRange = Selection

        End Sub

        'Ensures that the default starting point is midway between the min and max values specified

        Sub scrollbar1_enter()

        Dim x As Double
        Dim y As Double
        y = MaxBox.Value
        x = MinBox.Value
        ScrollBar1.Value = (x + y) / 2

        Selection = SelRange

        End Sub

        'Sets all parameters in the scroll bar
        Private Sub Scrollbar1_Change()

        ScrollBar1.Max = MaxBox.Value
        ScrollBar1.Min = MinBox.Value

        ScrollBar1.LargeChange = IncBox.Value
        ScrollBar1.SmallChange = IncBox.Value

        Selection = ScrollBar1 + SelRange

        End Sub

        'Default on exit of userform
        Private Sub ScrollBar1_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)

        Dim x As Double
        Dim y As Double

        y = MaxBox.Value
        x = MinBox.Value

        ScrollBar1.Value = (x + y) / 2

        End Sub

        'ensures activecell is updated in real time with dragging of mouse
        Private Sub ScrollBar1_Scroll()

        Selection.Value = ScrollBar1.Value + SelRange

        End Sub
```

Comment: Wouldn't SelRange be a range rather than an integer?

Comment: I tried that and it gives me a "Object variable or with block variable not set" error and won't run.

Comment: if `SelRange` is a `Range` you need to assign to it using `Set` - `Set SelRange = Selection`.

Comment: I see. However when I do that with a number of cells I get an error from:
Selection= ScrollBar1.Value + SelRange. It also makes this increases and decrease very erratic when I try to alter only one cell.

Comment: you're trying to add a number to an object.  That doesn't make sense - you need to think more carefully about *what kind of thing* each variable or element represents.  It doesn't help that VBA will try and automatically convert in some circumstances.  See my answer below for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current code is working for one cell because the default property of the `Range` object is `Value`.  So you are putting the *value* in the selected cell into your variable.  But for multiple cells, the `Value` property will return an `Array` - which won't fit into the `Integer`.

It looks like you need to declare `selRange` as a `Range` then work with that:

```
Public selRange as Range
'...
If TypeName(Selection) = "Range" Then
        Set selRange = Selection
Else
        'handle case when something other than cell(s) are selected here
End If
'rest of your code here
```

Look up the [Range object reference in MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx) for info on working with `Range`.  The `Cells` and  `Value` properties will be particularly useful.  In particular, to increment each cell in a range you can do:

```
Dim getAllValuesAtOnceAsArray As Variant
getAllValuesAtOnceAsArray = selRange.Value

Dim singleCell As Range
For Each singleCell In selRange.Cells
        singleCell.Value = singleCell.Value + 1
Next singleCell

'Now write back the original values
selRange.Value = getAllValuesAtOnceAsArray
```

One thing to note is that `Range.Value` always returns a 2D array if there is more than one cell (even if the range has only one row or one column).  So `getAllValuesAtOnceAsArray(rowNumber,columnNumber)` gets a single element of the array - and you need both indices even if one is always 1.  In practice it's usually easier to just use the `Range` object as there are more flexible ways of accessing the individual cells (`Cells`, `Offset`, `Rows`, `Columns` etc).

Comment: Done that now, thanks for your help. I will post what I did in full later for other people who may have a similar issue in future.